# angularjs view does not update after $http

Tags: angularjs, http, scope

> edit: I'm using bootstrap, I think bootstrap tab is causing the
>   problem

View does not get updated after $scope variable update.

> $scope.codeData

if i console the $scope.codeData, i can see the data, but does not render in view.

I have to click twice to get the view render correctly.

is there anything wrong with my code??

Thank you.

**config**

```
angular.module('SPAroutes', ['ngRoute', 'SPAcontrollers',  'SPAdirectives'])

.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider',
function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/admin', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/views/admin.html',
        controller: 'adminCtrl',
        controllerAs: 'admin'
    })
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
}]);
```

**Controller.js**

```
angular.module('SPAcontrollers', ['ngRoute', 'SPAfactories',   'SPAdirectives']).controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$SPAaccount', function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,  $SPAaccount) {
    this.dataRetrive = function(category){
        $http.get('/ctrls/get/blockCode/header').then(function (res){
            $scope.codeData = res.data;
            console.log($scope.codeData);
            $('#headerTab').tab('show');
        }, function (err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    };
}]);
```

**admin.html**

```
{{codeData}}
```

Comment: $scope.$apply() will do the job. But it shouldn't be needed.

Comment: @atinder no, that is most certainly not the answer

Comment: When / where are you calling `dataRetrieve()`? Also, you appear to be mixing `$scope` with `controllerAs` which typically isn't what you want

Comment: Your `$scope.codeData` is in `$http.get` method. That is why it's not updating view. Assign the value of  `$scope.codeData` outside `$http.get`, it should work.

Comment: Changing the DOM from within a controller is also a bad idea. That's what directives are for

Comment: @KhalidHussain no, that's not right at all

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors in your browser console?

Comment: @Phil its uncertain thats why i have posted it as comment otherwise i would have posted it as answer.

Comment: @atinder there is nowhere in OP's controller code where executing `$scope.$apply()` will not trigger a _"digest already in progress"_ error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing up controllerAs with scope as phil mentioned in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274864/angularjs-view-does-not-update-after-http#comment60176553_36274864) on question. Instead of using scope here store values inside`this` reference something like this.

```
angular.module('SPAcontrollers', ['ngRoute', 'SPAfactories',   'SPAdirectives']).controller('adminCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', '$location', '$window', '$SPAaccount', function ($scope, $http, $location, $window,  $SPAaccount) {
    var admin = this;
    this.dataRetrive = function(category){
        $http.get('/ctrls/get/blockCode/header').then(function (res){
            admin.codeData = res.data;
            console.log(admin.codeData);
            $('#headerTab').tab('show');
        }, function (err){
            console.log(err);
        })
    };
}]);
```

and inside the view: **admin.html**

```
{{admin.codeData}}
```

[here](http://plnkr.co/edit/YtRL1phc49Sb8SzdMDel?p=preview) is working plunk for your refernce